# When creating a child process is it necessary to copy data from the parent process to the child process?

Tags: linux, fork

I learned that,in linux `fork()` is used to create a new process.  It allocates new memory for the child process then copies data from parent process to the child process such as file descriptors.  Then `exec()` can be used to load its own data and overwrite the process space.  But I wonder is it necessary to copy data of parent process to child process?  How about loading the real data of a child process to its process space directly?

Comment: Please try to improve your question (and your English; use a dictionnary ....). It looks like you are missing some basic understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about [fork (system call)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29), [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (the kernel is using the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)), [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write), [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) ...

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has several chapters explaining these difficult concepts.

Parent and child processes have different address spaces, but after the fork the parent & child address spaces are nearly equal (thanks to virtual memory & copy-on-write techniques). The only difference being the result of the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall (which is [almost] the only way to create a process)

The [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) is entirely replacing the address space (and execution context) of its invoking process and is used to start a new executable program (often an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary executable).

You don't need to copy data from parent to child process. The kernel is doing that magically for you.

You may want to do some [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) between parent and child, usually thru pipes (read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) & [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) & [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...), to be set up *before* the `fork`. You might want to use [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) -avoid it if you are a newbie, since it is tricky to use correctly- but you should care about synchronization. See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) for more.

Use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and study the source code of some free software shell (like `sash` or `bash`)

Comment: Do you mean what be copied are just address references?

Comment: Your present understanding of "copying" is actually naive. Follow the links I gave to you! The address space is *lazily* copied.