# c++ fork() and address space

Tags: c++, fork, gnu

Complete GNU `fork()` noob here. I need to fork N processes that will do exact same thing: allocate 2 arrays, initialize them and process the data. I tried the code that can be simplistically compressed into:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    double b = 0;

    double *a1, *a2;

    fork();

    a1 = new double[10];
    a2 = new double[10];

    // initialize and process data in a1 and a2 using an algorithm involving a and b.
}
```

Is my `fork()` in the right place in terms of creating copies of `a1` and `a2` for each process as well as copies of `a` and `b`? Or should declaration and/or initialization of `a` and `b` fall after the `fork()` call? Each process should have their own `a, b, a1 and a2`.

Comment: Near duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23170985/841108). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23170985/841108). And you should always keep, and test, the result of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: Yes, I can take a timeout and study the kernel internals for a few months or years, or get a tip from someone knowledgable and get going to solve the immediate issue worth a few minutes of writing essentially throw-away code. Yours is a 'long' answer and it is correct. But it's not what I need. Is there a 'short' answer: does the place of fork() call matter? And please downvote more! Smack the newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Address spaces of processes are always **distinct**, even if they are in a parent-child relationship.

Comment: a1 and a2 do not have point to the same locations in each process.

Comment: Not sure what that means - both answer and comment. What is 'parent-child relationship' as regards to my question? What does it mean that the address spaces are distinct?